# trying to get a value from table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get a value from a row on my table, but I only get one value

($now), the $next isn't showing up, and yes its not null.

```
$account = $_POST['name']; 
$get_next = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT next_vote FROM account.account WHERE login = '$account'");
$next = $get_next->fetch_object();
$now = date("d/m/Y", strtotime('today'));
echo $now;
echo $next;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Your code is vulnerable for SQL injections!**

You cannot output an object with echo. Just use this:

```
var_dump($next);
```

If you want to echo the next vote:

```
echo $next->next_vote;
```

Or:

```
$next = $get_next->fetch_object()->next_vote;
```

Comment: with the var_dump it returns NULL, and the value is on the table
and the $next->next_vote; doesn't return anything

Comment: @JoaoPaulo: Try it with `$get_next = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT next_vote FROM account.account WHERE login = '$account' LIMIT 1");` and then make `var_dump($get_next->fetch_object());`

Comment: What says `var_dump($get_next, mysqli_error($conn));`?

Comment: object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) } string(0) ""

Comment: @JoaoPaulo: There are no rows found. Just try this: `die("SELECT next_vote FROM account.account WHERE login = '$account'");`. Is the account correct? Try to execute in database directly.

Comment: ok so yes, the account was wrong, it was before the submit, but it returns a weird value:

object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["next_vote"]=> string(10) "24/05/2015" }

it should just be 24/05/2015

Comment: @JoaoPaulo: That is correct, because you fetch an object. See my answer, this is the solution for this. And please see the SQL injection vulnerable, this is very important. You can upvote my answer and mark it as solution if all is ok.

Comment: ty, but shouldn't the mysqli take care of the sql injections?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78610/discussion-between-joao-paulo-and-richard-reiber).